# Protocol, paradigm or software for authenticating web requests across one's own domains

Tags: security, api, authentication

### tl;dr

I am considering a webservice **design model** which consist of several services/subdomains, each of which may be implemented in different platforms and hosted in different servers.

The main issue is **authentication**. If a request for `jane`'s resources came in, can a split system authenticate that request as her's?

All services access the same DB layer, of course. So I have in mind a **single point of truth** each service can use to authenticate each request.

---

For example, `jane` accesses `www.site.com`, which renders stuff in her browser. The browser may send a client-side request to different domains of `site.com`, with requests like:

```
from internalapi.site.com fetch /user/users_secret_messages.json
from imagestore.site.com fetch /images/list_of_images
```

The authentication issue is: another user (or an outsider) can craft a request that can fool  a subdomain into giving them information they should not access.

---

So I have in mind a **single point of truth**: a central resource accessible by each service that can be used to authenticate each request.

In this pseudocode, `AuthService.verify_authentication()`  refers the central resource

```
//server side code:
def get_user_profile():
    auth_token=request.cookie['auth_token']
    user=AuthService.verify_authentication(auth_token)
    if user=Null:
        response.write("you are unauthorized/ not logged in")
    else:
        response.write(json.dumps(fetch_profile(user)))
```

---

**Question:** What **existing protocols, software or even good design practices** exist to enable flawless authentication across multiple subdomains?

---

I seen how OAuth takes the headache out of managing 3rd-party access and wonder if something exists for such authentication. I also got the idea from [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) and [TACACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TACACS).

This idea was the result of teamthink, as a way to simplify architecture (rather than handle heavy loads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a system that did this a little while ago. We were building shop.megacorp.com, and had to share a login with www.megacorp.com, profile.megacorp.com, customerservice.megacorp.com, and so on.

The way it worked was in two parts.

Firstly, all signon was handled through a set of pages on accounts.megacorp.com. The signup link from our pages went there, with a return URL as a parameter (so `https://accounts.megacorp.com/login?return=http://shop.megacorp.com/cart`). The login process there would redirect back to the return URL after completion. The login page also set an authentication cookie, scoped to the whole of the megacorp.com domain.

Secondly, authentication was handled on the various sites by grabbing the cookie from the request, then forwarding it via an internal web service to accounts.megacorp.com. We could have done this is a straightforward SOAP or REST query, with the cookie as a parameter, but actually, what we did was send a HTTP request, with the cookie added to the headers (sort of as if the user had sent the request directly). That URL would then come back as a 200 if the cookie was valid, serving up some information about the user, or a 401 or something if it wasn't. We could then deal with the user accordingly.

Needless to say, we didn't want to make a request to accounts.megacorp.com for every user request, so after a successful authentication, we would mark the user's session as authenticated. We'd store the cookie value and a timestamp, and if subsequent requests had the same cookie value, and were within some timeout of the timestamp, we'd treat them as authenticated without passing them on.

Note that because we pass the cookie as a cookie in the authentication request, the code to validate it on accounts.megacorp.com is exactly the same as handling a direct request from a user, so it was trivial to implement correctly. So, in response to your desire for "existing protocols [or] software", i'd say that the protocol is HTTP, and the software is whatever you can use to validate cookies (a standard part of any web container's user handling). The authentication service is as simple as a web page which prints the user's name and details, and which is marked as requiring a logged-in user.

As for "good design practices", well, it worked, and it decoupled the login and authentication processes from our site pretty effectively. It did introduce a runtime dependency on a service on accounts.megacorp.com, which turned out to be somewhat unreliable. That's hard to avoid.

And actually, now i think back, the request to accounts.megacorp.com was actually a SOAP request, and we got a SOAP response back with the user details, but the authentication was handled with a cookie, as i described. It would have been simpler and better to make it a REST request, where our system just did a GET on a standard URL, and got some XML or JSON describing the user in return.

Having said all that, if you share a database between the applications, you could just have a table, in which you record (username, cookie, timestamp) tuples, and do lookups directly in that, rather than making a request to a service.

The only other approach i can think of is to use public-key cryptography. The application handling login could use a private key to make a signature, and use that as the cookie. The other applications could have the corresponding public key, and use that to verify it. The keys could be per-user or there could just be one. That would not involve any communication between applications, or a shared database, following the initial key distribution.